# Facing issue with SQL query in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database scheme on MySQL and I would like to retrieve all elements for a speciic id.

[image: Database scheme]

So for instance, I would like to retrieve cities, categories, departments linked to the coupon_id=1 (and other fields).
I wrote the following SQL query but unfortunatelly could not get the desired result.

```
SELECT  cc_coupon.id_coupon as idCoupon, 
        cc_coupon.condition_coupon, 
        cc_coupon.description, 
        cc_coupon.type_coupon, 
        cc_coupon_by_categorie.id_categorie, 
        cc_categorie.categorie as category, 
        cc_annonceur.raison_sociale, 
        cc_coupon_active_in_cities.id_ville as ville_slug, 
        cc_villes_france.ville_slug, 
        cc_villes_france.ville_nom_departement,
        cc_villes_france.ville_departement
FROM cc_coupon, 
     cc_coupon_by_categorie, 
     cc_categorie, 
     cc_annonceur, 
     cc_coupon_active_in_cities, 
     cc_coupon_active_in_departments,
     cc_villes_france
WHERE cc_coupon.id_coupon = cc_coupon_by_categorie.id_coupon 
    and cc_categorie.id_categorie = cc_coupon_by_categorie.id_categorie 
    and cc_coupon.id_annonceur = cc_annonceur.id_annonceur
    and cc_coupon.id_coupon = cc_coupon_active_in_cities.id_coupon 
    and cc_villes_france.id_ville = cc_coupon_active_in_cities.id_ville
    and cc_villes_france.ville_departement = cc_coupon_active_in_departments.ville_departement
    and cc_coupon.id_coupon = 1 
    and cc_coupon_active_in_cities.id_coupon = 1 
    and cc_coupon_active_in_departments.id_coupon = 1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So whats wrong with your result? Just a tip, sample data, current result and wanted result could give us a clue!

Comment: in fact with this query, I get no results.

Comment: Remove conditions, one at the time, and see what happens. Try with = 1 first.

Comment: What I expect is to have result which presents lines (as many as there is category multiply by the linked cities and cities) with id_coupon, id_category, category, RS, id_ville, ville_name, ville_departement

Comment: Start with a smaller join (just two tables), and extend it step by step - until you reach the final query!

Comment: don't you think that MAYBE, just MAYBE, there are no rows that match the requested conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `on` and not `where` when you want to join two tables. When you want to specify other conditions use `where` clause.